# How text color for all Android 4.0+ versions AND all languages?

Tags: android

Suppose I want to color part of text (words do you) in the sentence.

So I use this:

```
<string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font color="#00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>
```

But this not work on Android 4.0.

So for fix this I use next:

```
<string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>
```

But this not work for Android 4.3

So for fix this I use helper method:

```
 public static void setColor(TextView view, String fulltext, String subtext, int color) {
        view.setText(fulltext, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        Spannable str = (Spannable) view.getText();
        int i = fulltext.indexOf(subtext);
        str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), i, i + subtext.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

And use this method like this:

```
String fulltext = myTextView.getText().toString();
        AndroidUtil.setColor(myTextView, fulltext, fulltext.substring(7, 13),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getWzManager().getContext(), R.color.welcome_text_color));
```

But this work only for one language English. I know start/end indexes (**7, 13**).

But on another language (e.g. Spain) the start/end indexes are different.

So how I can fix this?

Comment: If the text to be colored is a pattern or known to you in hand then you  can use `regex`.

Comment: try using both attributes - the one, that works for 4.3, and for 4.0:    
`<string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font fgcolor="#FF00FFFF" color="#00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>`

Comment: Thanks. This work on all Android 4.0+ AND all languages:
<string name="congratulations">Hello, how <font color="cyan" fgcolor="#FF00FFFF">do you</font> do</string>

Comment: I found that this not work on device:  OS Version: 4.4.2
 Device: HTC Desire 610. So at finally I use this solution: <string name="expand"><![CDATA[<font color=#00FFFF>+</font> My contacts]]></string>. Of course you need in java code use this: Html.fromHtml(source);  So now it's work for all Adnroid 4.0+ and for all languages.